# Heroku app POST requests stop working after 2 mins of being idle

Tags: heroku, web-applications, timeout, mean-stack

I'm using loopback and the MEAN stack for a web Heroku app, and the app works fine until I open a new tab and do not interact with the Heroku app for exactly 2 minutes. After this, none of the POST requests work at all, and the $scope variables defined in controllers become undefined. It remains like this until I "heroku restart".

If I am interacting with the app, everything works for all time until I stop interacting with the app for 2 minutes.

Everything works fine locally, and the Heroku logs only give me an H12 timeout error when the POST requests fail.

Here is the [Heroku Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EbrN.png) Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you please attach Heroku logs? anythings outstanding there?

Comment: @GuyDubrovski I attached the log to the original post. Basically everything looks fine until the H12 timeout error...Which only happens after I don't interact with the app for 2 minutes. It seems like the controller $scope variables become undefined after the 2 minutes and before the H12 error

Comment: Can you check if the instance goes to sleep when the error occurs? What server are you using?

Comment: GET requests keep on working after 2 mins?